Spurious Spacing with tabular
Using tabular and array seems to be inserting an additional space in the right column of the first row:

If I remove the leading space (ie, use &Some Text instead of & Some Text, then the spacing is correct.
Listfiles:
 article.cls    2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
mathtools.sty    2024/10/04 v1.31 mathematical typesetting tools
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
    calc.sty    2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2024/11/05 v2.17t AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
   array.sty    2024/10/17 v2.6g Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3backend-xetex.def    2024-05-08 L3 backend support: XeTeX
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2024/08/06 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex

Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

%\listfiles
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{tabular}{r@{}ll@{}}
\( x \) & \( {}= y \) & Some Text  \\ 
\( x \) & \( {}= y \) & Some Other Text \\ 
\end{tabular}%
\par}

\[
\begin{array}{r@{}ll@{}}
  x & {}= y & \text{Some Text}  \\ 
  x & {}= y & \text{Some Other Text} \\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}


I get this output with an up to date texlive, can you show your log

that listfiles isn't from that document (it doesn't include mathtools)

but if I replace mathtools by amsmath I still get good output and same list as you  article.cls    2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2024/06/29 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
amsmath.sty    2024/11/05 v2.17t AMS math features
amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
array.sty    2024/10/17 v2.6g Tabular extension package (FMi)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)

Can you provide us your log file please?

@Skillmon: I am also on TeXLive and just updated all packages prior to filing this bug. But, now it seems that the space in the array version is not showing up. What is the best way to share the log file?

@Skillmon: Here is a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/v2erndfw6ml687jt9e9z1/ADwy_vv29-_-LqpfNFtWW6s?rlkey=4vxyhsr9bn7pe1yisnl1n8lh1&dl=0. Let me know if there is a better way to share this log file.

you could simply add it to the question, it's not that big,

There are only white space differences between my log and yours....

Aside: You should consider leaving XeTeX behind (see ltnews40 for reasoning).

If I add \tabcolsep=\arraycolsep to the preamble, the outputs of tabular and array are identical on my fully up to date MacOS/MacTeX2024 system.

It seems that I can no longer reproduce the problem. Not sure what is going on. The original source of this problem that I was helping someone editing a LibreText book and noticed that weird spacing problem. So, I tried it using TeXLive 2024 (with fully updated packages) and was surprised to see the same issue. I did not update any packages since posting the question.

I can reproduce the issue if I replace the space before “Some text” with U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE.

@egreg: Yeah that must have been the problem in that there was some invisible character.  Thanks everyone for your help.
